# compare this week and last week using a loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I want to compare the percentage of animal counts by this week and last week data but I'm stuck at comparison algorithm. I merely able to generate the data.

```
let data = []
for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

  let dog_count = _.random(0, 100),
    cat_count = _.random(0, 100)
  data.push({
    date: moment().subtract(i, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    total_count: dog_count + cat_count,
    dog_count,
    cat_count

  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xrx2aebx

The output I try to achieve is this

```
...
[{
date: '2017-8-10',
dog: {
    percentage: 67,
    indicator: 1 //1 means greater, 0 means equal, -1 means lesser
},
cat: {
    percentage: 33,
    indicator: -1
}]
...
```

Comment: What are you comparing to what? From your question I understand you want to compare this week's values to last week's values, but your example suggests you try to compare cats and dogs for each day separately.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele for example in monday (a date), dog's count of monday versus dog count of previous monday, same for cat.

Answer (score 0):

I used part your code and added little thinks trying to set your expected output. I think this is what you want. You can improve the code a lot, it was done in 5 min.

```
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    let dog = [];
    let cat = [];
  let dog_count = _.random(0, 100),
  cat_count = _.random(0, 100)
  var total_count = dog_count + cat_count;

  var cat_count_perc = cat_count/total_count;
  var dog_count_perc = dog_count/total_count;
  var cat_int = 0;
  var dog_int = 0;

  if(dog_count_perc > cat_count_perc)
  {
    dog_int = 1;
    cat_int = -1;
  }else if (cat_count_perc > dog_count_perc)
  {
    dog_int = -1;
    cat_int = 1;
  }
  dog.push({
  percentage: dog_count_perc.toFixed(2),
  indicator: dog_int
  });
  cat.push({
  percentage: cat_count_perc.toFixed(2),
  indicator: cat_int
  })
  data.push({
    date: moment().subtract(i, 'd').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    dog: dog,
    cat: cat

  })
}
console.log(data);
```

**jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/xrx2aebx/1/

Comment: dog and cat shouldn't be an array but object.

Comment: I want to compare says today (thursday) to previous thursday, your loop logic is wrong.

Comment: Well, is hard to understand what you want with your main post. Please, edit it and we will be able to help you.

Comment: it's not hard, compare latest 7 days with previous 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code

```
1. Generate last week's data, ordered by date(let lastWeekData)
2. Generate current week's data, ordered by date(let currentWeekData)
3. declare output array(let output = [])
4. for(var i=0;i< currentWeekData.length;i++){
    var currentOutput = {date: currentWeekData[i].date, dog: {},cat: {}};
    currentOutput.dog.percentage = currentWeekData[i].dog_Count / lastWeekData[i].dog_Count * 100; //here you need to change the percentage formula based on your requirement
    currentOutput.cat.percentage = currentWeekData[i].cat_Count / lastWeekData[i].cat_Count * 100;
    output.push(currentOutput);
}
```

Change your percentage formula accordingly.